# Difference between three queries

Tags: mysql, sql

First I will post the right solution for an exercise:
Exercise: Get part numbers for parts that are not supplied to project J3.

```
SELECT pno
FROM p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM spj
    WHERE spj.pno = p.pno
      AND spj.jno = 'J3'
    );
```

My solution, neither of them is correct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pno
FROM (
  p INNER JOIN spj
    ON p.pno = spj.pno
  )
WHERE spj.jno <> 'J3';
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.pname
FROM (
  p INNER JOIN spj
    ON spj.pno = p.pno
  )
WHERE spj.jno NOT IN ('J3');
```

I have 2 solutions, which I think they should give the same answer, but they don't. My question is that what is the difference. (My solution includes all parts, and the right solution doesn't include Part 3)

Comment: This place is not for having others do your homework, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha: actually, stackoverflow isn't against homework it's against people not trying anything themselves ;) Also see the policy here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: he put effort into it, developed different solutions. To ask why his solutions arent working is absolutely ok! THis is not just posting an assignment.

Comment: @Wolph: This has nothing to do with rules or anything. This is plain common sense: you cannot learn anything from your homework if you have others do it.

Comment: He's not asking for us to do his homework, he's asking what the difference between the solutions is and why they don't work. That's a different question.

Comment: @arkascha This is not my homework, if it were, I would not have a solution. I just wanna understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd query, you are looking for the combination of the parts and projects which are not identical to jno j3. Effectively this gives you all parts which are linked to projects which are not j3, but that doesn't say that the project doesn't have that part at all. You are just excluding those results.

For example:

```
Project  Part
1        j3
1        a1
2        a1
3        j3
```

Both project 1 and 2 will be returned because both have a part that's different from j3. Only 3 will be excluded because there are not parts other than j3 to match.

---

As for the 3rd query, it effectively does the same.

Comment: This is really great, now I understand!